# How to modify or get an object already created in other class (stats)?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I want to use the already created objects between more classes.

I wanted to make a Stats class which can handle receiving/giving money etc. but I think it is not the correct way making it a static(the object). I tried with other class, but outside of main and it did not work.

Here is Stats class. The constructors, getters and setters are basic.

```
public class Stats{
    int money;
    /**Constructor,Getter,Setter*/
    static Stats stats = new Stats(0);
}
```

Here worked

```
public class Main{
    public static void main ( String[] args){
    Stats.stats.setMoney(500);
    System.out.println(Stats.stats.getMoney());
    }
}
```

Here Stats.stats are colored, but not the method.

```
public class Shop {
    Stats.stats.getMoney();
}
```

I expect to call Class.object.method from any class, even if the object is not created in that class.

Answer (score 1):

> Stats.stats are colored, but not the method.

It probably couldn't resolve `stats` because of its access modifier, which is package-private. Changing it to `public` would make it compile.

> Even if the object is not created in that class.

Actually, the object `new Stats(0)` was created after the class was loaded. If it hadn't, you would have got an NPE in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be the answer you are looking right now but I want to mention it just in case.

As you mentioned

> I want to use the already created objects between more classes.

Now you can use static class/method/variables to do your job but don't forget Java is OOP.

> A static member is a member of a class that isn’t associated with an instance of a class. Instead, the member belongs to the class itself.

This allows you to access them without using objects. If you use static too much you won't be taking advantage of Java's actual feature i.e objects and classes.

I can do the same thing you are trying to do without using static. In java when an object is created it hold the information of where the data is located in memory. Something like this.

```
Dog tuffy = new Dog("tuffy","papillon",5, "white");
```

[image: Object]

Now to pass an object to another class all I need is to pass that address which will allow me to manipulate data/access members etc....

> Main Class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stats stats = new Stats(1000);
        System.out.println("Stats Money: " + stats.getMoney());
        // Passing the object also known as pass by reference
        Shop shop = new Shop(stats);
        System.out.println("Shop Money: " + shop.getMoney());
    }
}
```

> Stats Class

```
public class Stats {
    private int money;

    public Stats(int m) {
        this.setMoney(m);
    }

    public int getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    public void setMoney(int money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

}
```

> Shop Class

```
public class Shop {
    private Stats stats;

    public Shop(Stats stats) {
        this.stats = stats;
        // Now here using stats object you can do whatever you want
    }

    public int getMoney() {
        return stats.getMoney();
    }
}
```

Main Output:

```
Stats Money: 1000
Shop Money: 1000
```

For more please take a look at this website. [Classes and Objects in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/classes-objects-java/)

Comment: I still cannot get the money from stats in Shop class, but i will read the link you have given to me. Thanks.

Comment: @DanutDp Are you saving the reference somewhere in Shop class and What are you passing as parameter?